# How to delete the newline before EOF in a text/csv file via bash

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, newlines

Below is an example of the data I'm receiving in `txt` or `csv` file (seen in `EmEditor`):

[image: Problem Data]

However, the final blank line is causing problems when uploading this data into my software. I need to have the data look like the following.

[image: Corrected Data]

Would anyone be able to write a code to delete this final next line command and move the end of file command to the last line?

Comment: Is that a final blank line (i.e. the file ends with two newline characters), or is that software that interprets a final newline as starting an empty line (which is incompatible with C and Unix's definition of text file, but sometimes happens with broken Windows software)?

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways to do that.

With `printf`:

```
printf "%s" "$(<file)"
```

With `perl` (use `-i` to edit the file in-place):

```
perl -pe 'chomp if eof' file
```

Or with `head` (if you are sure that the last character is a newline):

```
head -c -1 file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
sed 'N; $ s/\n//; P; D;' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick also, and is a little more readable (in my awk-biased opinion):

```
 awk '{ if ( NR == 1) { printf("%s",$0); } else { printf("\n%s", $0); }}' file
```

Answer (score -1):

With `awk`:

```
awk 'NR > 1 { print prev } { prev = $0 }' file
```

or with `sed`:

```
sed '$d' file
```

Comment: Both of your solutions will delete the *whole* last line, not just the ending newline.